# Which azure affinity group should I choose for UK?

Tags: azure

Simple question - should the UK considered part of North Europe or West Europe when choosing a Microsoft Azure Affinity Group?

[image: Create Storage on Windows Azure]

Comment: Contact the Azure Infinity group.

Comment: The Microsoft website explicitly encourages it's users to use Stack Overflow for Azure support: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/forums/

Comment: Plus, what on earth is the "Azure Infinity group"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Azure doesn't have any data centres in the UK.

West Europe would be Amsterdam.

North Europe would be Ireland.

Comment: So, North Europe ought to be a better choice then?

Comment: @Hainesy, wasn't me! Have upvoted to balance it out. It's an OK question in my book, but hey ho, that's anonymous voting for you! And if location is that much of an issue and you *need* it as close to the UK as possible, then yeah. However, personally I've got subscriptions on both North & West Europe and see *no* obvious performance differences when I'm working (I am from the UK). There may be a slight performance difference but you will need to profile it.

Comment: Remember than "Location" and an "Affinity Group" are not necessarily the same.  The Location in the portal refers to a Windows Azure data center (West Europe, East US, etc.).  An affinity group is contained within a data center and is essentially a way to keep related resources physically close together.

Comment: I guess Amsterdam is technically slightly closer to London, while Ireland is closed to more northern England.  I guess Amsterdam also has good connectivity to mainland Europe. Then again, things so fast might not make any real difference between Amsterdam vs Ireland.

Comment: The UK has `UK West` and `UK South`...Although `UK West` is further South than `UK South`!

Answer (score 1):

You could also host your static content on the [Windows Azure Content Delivery Network](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/cdn/) (CDN). These items will then get served from London for those in the UK that are geographically closer to London than Dublin.

Here is a list of CDN locations:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/gg680302.aspx

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was doing, but they still require you to choose an affinity group.

Comment: Yep, as Arran mentioned North Europe is your best bet! I have a web-role deployed in Dublin with all images served from the CDN and the site is very quick. The weakest link is always SQL Azure in my case!